# Values are rendered in different cells after setup in cells which they don't fit to screen

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I select a product and added this to my cart , user can go to the cart page and edit the product.

If Edit is true I call the LoadValues and setup customised product.

For every extras in a product I create a ProductPropertiesCell and I add a values for this extra. (e.g Sugar -> No Sugar)

> ProductDetailsController.cs

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        ProductDetailsTable.Source = new ProductDetailsTableSource (this, SelectedProduct);
        ProductDetailsTable.ReloadData ();

        if (Edit) {
            ((ProductDetailsTableSource)ProductDetailsTable.Source).LoadValues (ProductDetailsTable);
        }

    }
```

Console output after LoadValues called.

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4 
>   extra 7
>
> 5
>   extra 10

For every cell i write the tag and the value which is added to this.

> ProductDetailsTableSource.cs

```
public class ProductDetailsTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    NSString cellIdentifier;

    public Product SelectedProduct { get; set; }

    public ProductDetailsController Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ProductDetailsTableSource(ProductDetailsController parent, Product product)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        SelectedProduct = product;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 3; //+3 for description, quantity, comment cell
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // Product Description
        if (indexPath.Section == 0)
        {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString("descriptionCell"); 
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as ProductDescriptionCell;
            cell.UpdateCell(SelectedProduct);

            return cell;
        }

        // Properties or Product Type Cell
        if (indexPath.Section <= SelectedProduct.Types.Count)
        {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString("propertiesCell"); 
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as ProductPropertiesCell;
            cell.UpdatePicker (this, SelectedProduct.Types [indexPath.Section - SelectedProduct.Props.Count - 1], indexPath);
            cell.Tag = indexPath.Section;
            return cell;
        }


        // Comments
        if (indexPath.Section == SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 1)
        {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString ("commentsCell");
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as CommentsCell;
            cell.Setup (tableView, indexPath);

            return cell;
        }

        // Quantity
        else {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString ("quantityCell");
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as QuantityCell;
            cell.UpdateData (Parent);
            return cell;
        } 

    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    }

    public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //Description
        if(indexPath.Section==0)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (SelectedProduct.Desc))
                return 0;
            else
            return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
            //return 80;
        }

        //pickers
        if (indexPath.Section <= SelectedProduct.Types.Count)
            return 80;

        //Comments
        if (indexPath.Section == SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 1)
        return 100;

        //Quantity
        if (indexPath.Section == SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 2)
            return 64;

        return 0;
    }

    public void LoadValues (UITableView tableView)
    {

        for (nint i = 1; i <= SelectedProduct.Types.Count; i++) {
            // we scroll to force our cells to be visible else they return null
            tableView.ScrollRectToVisible (tableView.RectForSection (i), true);

            var cell = ((ProductPropertiesCell)tableView.CellAt (NSIndexPath.FromRowSection (0, i)));
            Debug.WriteLine (cell.Tag);
            Debug.WriteLine (Parent.Info.SavedProductInstance [i]);
            cell.ValuePicked = Parent.Info.SavedProductInstance [i];

        }

        tableView.ScrollRectToVisible (tableView.RectForSection ((nint)SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 1), true);
        ((CommentsCell)tableView.CellAt (NSIndexPath.FromRowSection (0, (nint)SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 1))).Comments = Parent.OrderProduct.Comments;
        tableView.ScrollRectToVisible (tableView.RectForSection ((nint)SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 2), true);
        ((QuantityCell)tableView.CellAt (NSIndexPath.FromRowSection (0, (nint)SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 2))).Quantity = Parent.Info.Quantity;

        BeginInvokeOnMainThread (()=> tableView.ScrollRectToVisible (tableView.RectForSection (0), true));

    }

}
```

> ProductPropertiesCell.cs
>
> ```
>     public string ValuePicked
>     { 
>         get { return Picker.Text; }
>         set { Picker.Text = value; }
>     }
> ```

When cells are too much and don't fit to screen then the values are rendered in a different cells.

[image]

When all cells fit to screen, it's working perfect.

Comment: Hi , not too much understandinng your problem. "When cells are too much and don't fit to screen then the values are rendered in a different cells."

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Inside to LoadValues i get every cell and add a value. Only the cell with tag 5 has a value (look my console output), but on emulator with small screen, this value (ΣΧΟΛΙΟ 9 , ΣΧΟΛΙΟ 10), is added to cell with tag 2 (the cell with tag 2 must be empty , only 5 must have a value) (look the emulator)

Comment: Okey , thanks for replying .What do you mean by the content that should have been displayed on the cell of Tag5, and the result is displayed on the cell of Tag2?

Comment: Update my screenshot , please look. Thanks

Comment: The cells tag is just indexpath section , i added for debug .
cell.Tag = indexPath.Section;

Comment: Have a checking this line of code `cell.UpdatePicker (this, SelectedProduct.Types [indexPath.Section - SelectedProduct.Props.Count - 1], indexPath); ` , and if you set `indexPath.Section` to Tag , the number should start from 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197151/discussion-between-junior-jiang-msft-and-g-mich).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks again for your help. My code working perfect when all my cells are visible to screen. If i run my app on bigger emulator all cells are visible to screen without scrolling and its working. This line started from 1 because i dont want the cell with indexpath 0 (its the decription cell), I dont want to put some value on this cell

Comment: Okey ,got it . You should reuse cell when scrolling .

Answer (score 1):

> My code working perfect when all my cells are visible to screen. If i run my app on bigger emulator all cells are visible to screen without scrolling and its working.

```
if (cell == null)
{ 
      cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier); 
 }
```

From this phenomenon ,I guess your problem is not reusing cell in table view like up code .eg : modifying your code as follow.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // Product Description
        if (indexPath.Section == 0)
        {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString("descriptionCell"); 
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as ProductDescriptionCell;
            if (cell == null)
            { 
               cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier); 
             // Here you can modify UITableViewCell to your custom cell
             //cell = new ProductDescriptionCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier)
            }

            cell.UpdateCell(SelectedProduct);

            return cell;
        }

        // Properties or Product Type Cell
        if (indexPath.Section <= SelectedProduct.Types.Count)
        {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString("propertiesCell"); 
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as ProductPropertiesCell;
            if (cell == null)
            { 
               cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier); 
             // Here you can modify UITableViewCell to your custom cell
             //cell = new ProductPropertiesCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier)
            }

            cell.UpdatePicker (this, SelectedProduct.Types [indexPath.Section - SelectedProduct.Props.Count - 1], indexPath);
            cell.Tag = indexPath.Section;
            return cell;
        }


        // Comments
        if (indexPath.Section == SelectedProduct.Types.Count + 1)
        {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString ("commentsCell");
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as CommentsCell;
            if (cell == null)
            { 
               cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier); 
             // Here you can modify UITableViewCell to your custom cell
             //cell = new CommentsCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier)
            }

            cell.Setup (tableView, indexPath);

            return cell;
        }

        // Quantity
        else {
            cellIdentifier = new NSString ("quantityCell");
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as QuantityCell;
            if (cell == null)
            { 
               cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier); 
            // Here you can modify UITableViewCell to your custom cell
             //cell = new QuantityCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier)
            }

            cell.UpdateData (Parent);
            return cell;
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Every time variable cell is not null 
  
  // if cell is not available in reuse pool, iOS will create one automatically
    // no need to do null check and create cell manually
    var cell = (MyCell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MyCellId, indexPath);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data#subclassing-uitableviewsource

Answer (score 0):

I remove

```
    if (Edit) {
        ((ProductDetailsTableSource)ProductDetailsTable.Source).LoadValues (ProductDetailsTable);
    }
```

and the LoadValues method.

I update the values directly to cell, like this

```
    // Properties or Product Type Cell
    if (indexPath.Section <= SelectedProduct.Types.Count)
    {
        cellIdentifier = new NSString("propertiesCell"); 
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as ProductPropertiesCell;
        cell.UpdatePicker (this, SelectedProduct.Types [indexPath.Section - SelectedProduct.Props.Count - 1], indexPath);

        //Edit mode -> add selected value
        if (Parent.Edit)
            cell.ValuePicked = Parent.Info.SavedProductInstace[indexPath.Section];

        return cell;
    }
```

Now it's working !!

Comment: Great , glad you find the solution :)